# Providing an AppID, and AppSecret when building a REST API in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api

I am building a REST API using NodeJS and MongoDB, and one of the features of REST API's that are made available for developers (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Google etc) is to generate a unique AppID, and App Secret when developers register with your API on your site.  What I would like to know is how does one provide a feature such that each AppID and App Secret pair is unique for each developer who registers, and what features/traits should the AppID, and AppSecret have in order to conform to other standard API's like Facebook, and Google (e.g. length, character composition)?  How would I implement the generation of this code in JavaScript, and then store it in MongoDB for a user who registers with my API?

Just wondering.

Comment: Multiple ways to do this, but take a look at passport.js.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.  Can you be a bit more specific as to how I can use PassportJS to implement this feature?

Comment: I think the best explanation is http://passportjs.org.  There are plugins for most known authentications systems, and if you want your own api-key/secret auth you can build that too.